# Salesforce Custom Field APi

Tags: api, integration, custom-field

I have created a new field in Salesforce on Order Product called **'Delivery Mode'**. The API name is '**Delivery_Mode__c**'.

I use this API in integration to an ERP but it is giving me an error.

The error is:

```
{"compositeResponse":[{"body":[{"id":"801Pz000004MNoUIAW","success":true,"errors":[],"created":false}],"httpHeaders":{},"httpStatusCode":200,"referenceId":"OrderHeader"},{"body":[{"success":false,"errors":[{"statusCode":"INVALID_FIELD","message":"No such column 'Delivery_Mode__c' on sobject of type OrderItem","fields":[]}],"created":false}],"httpHeaders":{},"httpStatusCode":200,"referenceId":"OrderItems"}]}
```

Kindly assist with ideas to resolve

Comment: I think the reason for this error is that the field is not visible or accessible to the user or profile that is running the integration. You can check and edit the field-level security settings for the `Delivery_Mode__c` field. In Setup, go to Object Manager and select Order Product. Click Fields & Relationships in the sidebar, and then click the Delivery Mode field name. Click Set Field-Level Security in the Field Details section.
Select the checkbox for the user or profile that you want to grant access to the field, and choose the level of access, such as Visible or Read-Only.
Click Save.

Comment: Thank you Tushar Jadav. SOLVED!!!

Comment: Glad to hear that the issue is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the reason for this error is that the field is not visible or accessible to the user or profile that is running the integration.

You can check and edit the **field-level** security settings for the `Delivery_Mode__c` field.

- In Setup, go to Object Manager and select **Order Product**.
- Click **Fields & Relationships** in the sidebar, and then click the **Delivery Mode** field name.
- Click **Set Field-Level Security** in the Field Details section.
- Select the checkbox for the user or profile that you want to grant access to the field, and choose the level of access, such as Visible or Read-Only.
- Click Save.